Mysqli not showing anything on website (hot_info, exceptions)
some who doesn't know what they're doing here. I am trying to connect to a MySQL database with mysqli from a PHP site running on a local Apache server with PHP 8.3.7, but even when I supply the wrong credentials mysqli is not throwing an exception (not showing on website).
            echo nl2br("Hellolrd \n");
            echo "TEST 123456789";

            $servername_mysql = "localhost";
            $port_mysql = 3306;
            $username_mysql = "user1";
        $password_mysql = 1234;
            $database_mysql = "db1";
            $charset = "utf8mb4";

        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

            try {
                $db = new mysqli($servername_mysql, $username_mysql, $password_mysql,                   $database_mysql, $port_mysql);
                $db->set_charset($charset);
                $db->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, 1);
            } catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
                throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
            }
            unset($servername_mysql, $port_mysql, $username_mysql, $password_mysql, $database_mysql, $charset);

screenshot of website
I have tried to display host_info with echo, but that also showed nothing. I know that the database is live and working as I managed to connect to it with the MySQL shell on windows and use some commands. The top two lines are showing so my PHP interpreter is working fine. I am following this guide. I am going kinda insane here, hopefully somebody here can help me. Thanks in advance.

It seems you forgot to configure PHP error reporting as well. On a live site exceptions should never be shown to site users, so by default displaying errors is turned off. So in the dev environment you have to turn them on. And PHP will readily start showing you exceptions

Also, unrelated but still: this ugly try-catch stuff is not needed anymore, and it can (and should) be removed. It was a leftover in this tutorial which is now fixed

@YourCommonSense Thank you so much! I have accidentally used the prod version of the ini file preset, so displaying errors was disabled and I also didn't have the mysqli extension enabled. I will get rid of the try-catch stuff, if you said that it isn't needed. I used it because the article said that credentials would be included in the exception (which should be turned off in prod anyway). Everything works as intended now.

exactly! But recently PHP implemented a great feature that made this code unnecessary
